# How to run Daphne Server (Django Channels) & workers in the background?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have installed Django Channels. I am trying to run the following commands to run Daphne server and a worker.

```
> daphne chat.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
> python manage.py runworker -v2
```

But each command opens up a live terminal showing logs. I just want to run them as background processes. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment **nohup &** is working alright for me. The following commands run the processes in the background.

```
> sudo nohup daphne MyProject.asgi:channel_layer --port 80 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2 &
> sudo nohup python manage.py runworker -v2 &
```

**kill -9 [pid]** should help kill them when needed.

Answer (score 3):

For these type of tasks, you should use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `circus`, `supervisor` or at least `systemd`.

Read [this article](http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/) to run easy and fast.